# Converting an ATL COM project to .NET

Tags: .net, com, .net-core, atl

I have bunch of ATL COM Dlls, which I want to re-use in a NET Core project.

After reading many questions on Stackoverflow near the topic, it seams that it's recommended to using COM interrop in CLR, instead of rewriting the ATL COM dlls in raw COM C++ CLR.

Why is that? Doesn't it create an extra overhead on the .NET core project? Will it work on non-Windows platforms, as they don't have COM?

Is it difficult to refactor ATL COM dlls to raw COM (C++ CLI)?

Br,
Johan

Comment: You don't need to convert anything, it should just work, but only of Windows. Windows itself is made of hundreds of COM objects written in C++. If you need cross-platform, you'll have to rewrite all COM objects functionality in whatever language depending on the platform. Could be .NET core C#

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for the answer. That's what I was afraid of.

Comment: Depending how factored your logic is, you can compile core C++ / C logic parts cross-platform, export an API as C methods and consume them from .NET Core via PInvoke-Methods (`DllImport` C# attribute).

Comment: @MartinUllrich Thanks for that. I was thinking that would be possible. Do I have to compile the C++ parts in C++ ISO then? Would C++ CLI only be usable in Windows CLR?

Comment: C++/CLI is a technology of the "desktop CLR" as part of the full .NET Framework. The CoreCLR (used in .NET Core) can (as well as the desktop CLR) load any native library and provide C-based interop via PInvoke / Marshalling.